# Logged as main user but can't access anything

Tags: permissions, login, users

After ordinary use of Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday I shut it down, and today after logging in as user "biowar", I cannot access any app, for example Nautilus:

[image: Photo of screen with Nautilus open on Home "location could not be displayed"]

> This location could not be displayed
> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "biowar"

Some terminal output after probing:

[image: Photo of screen with terminal emulator]

```
bash: /home/biowar/.bashrc: Permission denied
biowar@Nitro5:/$ whoami
biowar
biowar@Nitro5:/$ firefox
Error: Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory
biowar@Nitro5:/$
```

I searched for files, and they are okay, as well as permissions. How can I troubleshoot the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was an issue. `auth.log/boot.log/dpkg.log` didn't show any errors or alerts at all. And files permissions were set correctly. Finally I tried `sudo chown biowar:biowar /home/biowar` without `-R` option and it worked. But I still have no idea what caused the problem.